# Mysql insert just part of string and don't report error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I probably have some injection error in my code, but I don't know where this is happening.

```
$name = 'Toshiba LED TV 32" 32W2333D HD Ready';

$query = "UPDATE `tv`
         SET `title` = '" . $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($name). "'
         WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'";

$prep = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
$prep->execute();
```

Instead to get in field title:

> Toshiba LED TV 32" 32W2333D HD

I get:

> Toshiba LED TV 32"

Comment: and the `where` is probably wrong too. `WHERE '42'`? perhaps it should be `WHERE id = '42'` or something. Since you're using mysqli, why are you manually escaping anyways? Why not use a prepared statement and placeholders?

Comment: @MarcB Probably? - Nah; is. Definitely missing an equal sign. OP's probably not showing us actual used code. Edit: It's been changed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i added that, sorry, there is no id field just wanted to give sample.

Comment: if you pass the $name as 

    Toshiba LED TV 32 32W2333D HD
, will you still having that issue?

Comment: Or the title field is set to varchar(18)?

Comment: @HansDubois no, varchar 256

Comment: @peterpeterson no, without quotes works ok

Comment: ok so the problem is how you scape the characters. what is inside the method: $this->mysqli->real_escape_string ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use bind parameters?
Like:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tv SET title = ? WHERE id = ?");
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$results =  $statement->bind_param($product_title, $find_id);
```